# What is the advantage of adversary if the random number repeats?

Tags: encryption, random-number-generator, chosen-plaintext-attack, adversarial-model

In proof of CPA-security of encryption scheme $(r, F_k(r)\oplus m )$
where:

- $F_k$ is a keyed function
- $r\in_R\{0,1\}^n$ is a random number,
  on page 85 of [Introduction to modern cryptography](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Ejkatz/imc.html) we have

> The value $r^*$ is used when answering at least one of A’s encryption oracle queries: In this case, A may easily determine whether $m_0$ or $m_1$
> was encrypted. This is so because if the encryption oracle ever returns
> a ciphertext $\langle r^*,s \rangle$, si in response to a request to encrypt the message $m$,
> the adversary learns that $f(r^*) = s\oplus m.$

- My question is how can the adversary use $f(r^*)$?
- Haven't we assume that the adversary doesn't know about $f$?

What I understand is that if we have used the keyed function $F_k$, then since the adversary doesn't know $k$, the knowledge of $F_k(r^*)$ can't be used because s/he still needs lots of time, that is $2^{|k|}$, to check which function $F_k$ where used. So it seems to me using the encryption scheme is secure even we repeat the random number $r$.

It seems that I am missing something but I can't find it.

Comment: Hint: imagine you are the adversary playing the [IND-CPA game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability#Indistinguishability_under_chosen-plaintext_attack_(IND-CPA)). Assume that in step 4 the challenger reuses one of the $r_i$ used in step 2. How do you play to detect that, detect which $r_i$ was reused, and win the game with certainty?

Comment: @fgrieu Thanks. Although I didn't like to think like an adversary when I think like her/him I understand that the whole point isn't to find the $F_k$ function. It seems if $r$ repeats, then he can *distinguishes$ between two messages.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @fgrieu I've got the point I've missed.
The point is **the adversary doesn't want to find the keyed function**, of course, s/he would be happy if knew it, but s/he wants information and wins some game.

So Let's think like an adversary and we have asked $z$ queries $m_1, \cdots, m_z$ and got $\langle r_1, F_k(r_1)\oplus m_1\rangle, \cdots , \langle r_z, F_k(r_z)\oplus m_z\rangle$. We can have the following information from the queries' answers.

$F_k(r_1) = F_k(r_1) \oplus m_1 \oplus m_1$

$\vdots$

$F_k(r_z) = F_k(r_z) \oplus m_z \oplus m_z$

Then we choose $m'$ and $m''$ and get one more ciphertext $F_k(r')\oplus m_b$. **If random number r repeats, for example r'= r_i**, then we can do the following computation

$F_k(r_i)\oplus m_i \oplus m_i \oplus F_k(r') \oplus m_b = m_b$

And we exactly know which message was encrypted just by checking whether $m_b = m'$ or $m_b=m''$.

Even the adversary still doesn't know the $F_k$ we used he win CPA-game.

Answer (score 0):

Look at page 47 at "A Graduate Course in Applied Cryptography"
(there they also show a Attack Game)

https://toc.cryptobook.us/

$PRG_{adv}[A,G]:= |Pr[W_0] - Pr[W_1] |$

*(Illustrated in Fig. 3.1 as in the book)*

"Attack Game 3.1 can be recast as a “bit guessing” game"

Comment: Or I maybe misunderstood the question, sorry -if I did , please  say that.     "What is advantage of adversary if the random number repeats?" - You can change the game (in the book I provided) slightly so that they use repeating numbers  (As fgrieu wrote in a comment)

Comment: & I'm sorry again; I'm a bit new,  (to this site, overall) So I haven't got used to the symbol-formattings.

Comment: There is no need to be sorry at all. Your answer provides some new information to me about the definition of *advantage of adversary* and new games though doesn't exactly answered it. Thanks.

Comment: @Doralisa Oh, Okay thanks so much;  Have a great day, & good luck :)  (Just wanted to say this)